# Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> Cкрин:
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Selenium не могу нажать на кнопку отвечающую за время. Пробовал через XPath, пробовал через поиск класса, пробовал через весь путь. Пробовал нажимать как на li, так и на span который внутри li. Результат - 0.

Часть кода отвечающая за это окно:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('js-show-request-popup').click() #Открывает все это окно
sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_class_name('b-selectbox').click() #Открывает список (таблицу) с временами
sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[22]/div/div[1]/ul/li[25]').click() # Попытка нажать на 14:30 (НЕУДАЧНО)
```

> Как найти эту всю белеберду :
>   [Ссылка на страницу](https://ru.wargaming.net/clans/wot/recruit_members/)
>   Вы должны состоять в клане и иметь возможность набирать бойцов > Нажать на "Изменить условия подбора".

Так же прошу чекнуть эту тему на другом форуме, там предложили решение, но не объяснили как сделать(((
https://koreanrandom.com/forum/topic/54897-selenium-python/

Comment: Неохота регистрироваться на сайте, но предполагаю, что между первым тэгом body и твоей кнопкой есть Клемент frame.  Можешь ли в спойлер как то или ссылку на сохранённую страницу приложить, чтобы не объяснять, как сделать, а прикрепить скриншот , как сделать

Comment: Скопируйте, пожалуйста, сообщение из консоли: какое именно исключение происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Не все элементы "кликабельны". Попробуйте в ближнем дереве найти элемент ссылки, кнопки или на подобие таких вещей.